# Python module import not working

Tags: python, python-import, getcwd

I am getting an error with the following code:

```
from os import getcwd
os.getcwd()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
os.getcwd()
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Anyone know why importing this way is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import getcwd
print getcwd()
```

When you have only imported `getcwd` and not `os` how can this work `os.getcwd`

Comment: Sure I understand now. I'm just new to python so still struggling with some few basics

Comment: @West if you do `import os`, then you can do the `.` part

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities. The first one is to import the module and name the module every time calling the function:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Or you can import the method of the module directly and don't have to name the module when calling it:

```
from os import getcwd
print getcwd()
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I guess I have to omit the module name whenever I use a function imported that way right?